# How can I push an aggregate initialiser list into a vector?

Tags: c++, c++03

I am trying to write something like that:

```
vector<iovec> iovecs;
iovec io = {&foo, sizeof(foo)};
iovevs.push_base(io);
```

which is ok for the compiler.

Now I am trying to transform it into something more concise, like that:

```
 vector<iovec> iovecs;
 iovecs.push_back({&foo, sizeof(foo)});
```

But I am rejected with error msg like:

```
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

I do not want to enable c++0x. Still I want to be able to uses the aggregates init style. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Is there really an error? What does the error say? What you copied is just a warning.

Comment: @tgmath you're right it is just a warning. But it's still annoying. How can I get rid of it.

Comment: @yvesBaumes how to disable the warning is beyond the scope of this question, please submit a new one (or search for an existing one that answers that question).

Comment: @tgmath: I get an error from the use of a C++11-only overload of `push_back`; so you probably really do have to enable C++11 in order to use this aspect of C++11.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Then I would like to have the error in the question for completeness. Could be the case that I stmple about smething like this in the future. Could you add it?

Comment: @tgmath: Not really; I don't know which compiler the OP is using, or indeed whether there is an error with that compiler. Any answer to the question of how to selectively enable some C++11 features while leaving the rest disabled will be highly compiler-specific, and not very useful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That usage of *braced-initializer* in terms of *uniform-initialization* is a feature introduced with C++11.

If you don't want to enable such compiler support you are quite naturally forced to work with what you have in the earlier standard(s); which, as you have already found out, doesn't include [*uniform-initialization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization).

---

A simple "hack" that might ease your pain would be something as the below:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
iovec make_iovec (T const& a, U const& b) {
 iovec  ret = {a, b};
 return ret;
}
```

```
iovecs.push_back (make_iovec (&foo, sizeof(foo)));
```

Comment: I'd name it make_iovec() instead. To be consistent with the std::make_pair() function name.

Comment: And by the way the braced-initiliser list is usable before c++11, but only in the context of aggrgates types. Am I wrong?

Comment: @yvesBaumes: Yes, aggregate initialisation has always been in C++, inherited from the equivalent in C. More general forms of brace initialisation were added in C++11.